# android okHttp no route to host exception why?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying to call http url using okHttp library using the code below:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
    builder.url(url);
    Request request = builder.build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       
        return e+"";
    }
```

The problem is the url is opened well and return data from browser of device, but when i try to call this function and passing the same url it return

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

Comment: Have you tried to access to that host through PostMan or via browser and check that that IP is working correctly?

Comment: yes i tried to call the same url from browser and it working normally

Comment: And the url is the same?